# linear regression for RNA seq analysis in R

Tags: r

I want to do linear regression analysis for `RNA` seq data for multiple files together without any replication and control. I do not want to perform a comparison with control, I want to basically run a linear regression. For example, I have 100 paired end input files for 100 different varieties. There are 25 different compound concentration for each variety. For example, I have a dataset for each compound which lists its concentration in all the varieties so I have 25 such excel files. I am using `salmon` to create `TPM` values and then I want to test for regression relationship between independent variable (each compound which is a vector of all 100 varieties) and dependent variable as TPM values from all the varieties. I already the TPM values in quant.sf files using salmon and I want to perform linear regression analysis in R. Can you help me on how to do it.

Thank you in advance for any suggestion/comment/guidance!

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If I understand you correctly, you're asking how to run a linear regression:

```
 model1 <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = iris)
 summary(model1)
```

I would start here and then revisit the rest of your question (e.g. perform on multiple files) once you get the initial regression up and running on your data.